# How can I interpret the Wilcoxon test and Kendall tau-b?

Tags: kendall-tau

For Wilcoxon test, I have p=0.000. I also did the Kendall's test to test the correlation, and I have Tb=0.366. I don't get it, if there is a significant difference, why there is a moderate agreement?

Comment: Kendall's test does not measure agreement; it measures correlation. Consider $y = x +\ $ an enormous constant by comparison. The correlation is perfect but the agreement is lousy

Comment: Concordance correlation: search the forum for mentions.

Comment: @NickCox Is there a missing symbol in your first comment?

Comment: No; suppose $y$ and $x$ differ only by an enormous constant, enormous being relative to the scale of either variable. Then any kind of correlation between $y$ and $x$ is 1, but they don't agree. I take it that perfect agreement means equality.